# Can I use 3rd party ad network ads in android webview app?

Tags: android, web-applications, webview, admob, adsense

I developed an app with android webview which loads webpages from my website. I have already implemented admob to the app. So can I put 3rd party ad network ads(chitika) to the webpages. Is it violates the google policies?